# Can I use one terminal for multiple files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]

[image]

Here's the error:

> C:\Users\smadu\Documents\CodeHouse\Program.cs(7,21): error CS0017:
> Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to
> specify the type that contains the entry point.

I'm fairly new to visual studio so this is probably a simple fix. I've got two files up and would like to run them both through the terminal.

How do I do so separately?

I found that the code as is won't run because I have two **"static void Main"s.** Changing one to say **static void Main2** will fix the error but only run the one without the 2.

Is there a way to run both files through the terminal or not? Thanks!

Comment: You would have to create two separate programs for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, and nothing at all to do with VSCode.  C# programs can only have one entry point. Why would you need more than one entry point, and how would you decide when to use one vs when to use the other??

Comment: you can have only 1 main method as entry point, and run diferrent actions inside

Comment: Its not possible to run on VS Code. 
Because it will find in all files the "static void main" and run. 

In VS Studio you can click on properties of file and set "not build".

Comment: The message you are getting tells you exactly what you have to do: "Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point."

Comment: If you were using Visual Studio (not Visual Studio code), you could create two projects in the same solution.  If the two "programs" use substantially the same code, create three projects, one, an EXE with your first `Main` method, another  EXE project (with the other `Main` method) and the third one a DLL (aka "library") with the common code.  Not sure how to do something like this in VS Code land

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* have multiple files with `Main()` but as noted above, you can only build and run 1 at a time.

In your project file `.csproj` file

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

        <!-- set your startup object -->
        <StartupObject>CodeHouse.Test</StartupObject>

    </PropertyGroup>
```

The above will run your `Test` console. To build/run your `Program` change `<StartupObject>` accordingly.

So end of the day, its really just one "app" (at a time), whatever use case you may have. I personally do this only for organizing some quick scripts/hacks in one physical location/folder/repo.

Hth..

Comment: That did it thanks man!

So StartupObject is just a way of specifying which console to build/run?

Comment: @Odagen Here's [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out!

Comment: @Odagen cool - if this resolves things, please mark this as the answer. Otherwise, just ask. Thnx!